# Error Code 551 while connecting a FTP server through .NET code

Tags: sql, email, ftp, response, biztalk

I am using the below c# code to connect the FTP server. Sometimes while sending the files it is getting the Error Code 551 with Description: Exception caught in sending FTP: The remote server returned an error: (551) Page type unknown.

I don't why this is happening.
Can anyone tell me what the issue is?

```
private bool sendFTP(string sDestPath, string sFileName, string sUserName, string sPassword, string sDomain, bool isProxyUsed, string sProxy, int nProxyPort, byte[] sData)
       {
           try
           {
               NetworkCredential nCred;
               if (!sDomain.Equals(String.Empty))
               {
                   nCred = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(sUserName, sPassword, sDomain);
               }
               else
               {
                   nCred = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(sUserName, sPassword);
               }
               FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(sDestPath + "//" + sFileName);
               request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
               request.Credentials = nCred;
               request.Proxy = new WebProxy();
               if (isProxyUsed)
               {
                   WebProxy p = new WebProxy(sProxy, nProxyPort);
                   p.Credentials = nCred;
                   WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy = p;
               }
               request.ContentLength = sData.Length;
               Stream reqStream = request.GetRequestStream();
               reqStream.Write(sData, 0, sData.Length);
               reqStream.Close();
               FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
               return true;
           }
           catch (Exception objEx)
           {
               // Error
               EventLog.WriteEntry("STCCommon", "Exception Caught:" + objEx.Message, EventLogEntryType.Error);
               throw new Exception("Exception caught in sending FTP: " + objEx.Message);
           }

       }
```

Comment: Why are you using C# to connect to an FTP server if you are using BizTalk?  BizTalk has an FTP Adapter.  Regarding the error code  http://www.serv-u.com/respcode.asp?resp=551&prod=su

Comment: This is project requirement

Comment: Well at this point I would fire the person who makes such silly requirements.  BizTalk has exception handling and automatic re-try ability built in.  If the error is intermittent then either you have a network connectivity issue or an issue on the target FTP server.  Maybe put a retry loop (with a maximum number of retries) in your code so it tries again after getting a 551 error and see if it works.